# Discord bot progress bar

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make a progress bar that's synced with the server member count on my discord.js bot.
For example the goal is 1000 members, and there are currently 100 in the server so the progress bar will be 10%.
I tried to look on Google for an example code but all I see is progress bars for CSS.
Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by a progress bar, what are you using to display the progress bar? where are you displaying it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving enough information you are simply asking for the code to a progress bar.

You should provide:

- code you tried or at least background info
- if you wanted text progress bar or image progress bar

Im not sure if you want something like:

[#########------]

or just the percentage

However, Im assuming youre saying text so you would need a formula but you can also just use a package called  progress

```
var ProgressBar = require('progress');

var bar = new ProgressBar(':bar', { total: 10 });
var timer = setInterval(function () {
  bar.tick();
  if (bar.complete) {
    console.log('\ncomplete\n');
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because V12 is released, I don't think there is an way to do that question, I attempted on.

> 'Answer: You can call the memberCount variable in the guild, EDIT: v12 discord.js doesn't support that anymore!'

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const cliProgress = require('cli-progress');
const b1 = new cliProgress.SingleBar({
  barCompleteChar: '\u2588',
  barIncompleteChar: '\u2591',
  hideCursor: true
});
b1.start(200, 0)
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      targetGuild = client.guilds.get('719015947209539585')
      
    // initialize the bar - defining payload token "speed" with the default value "N/A"
    b1.update(targetGuild.memberCount)
    
    }, 1000);

});
```

It result was just a frozen bar.